# MVC4 hyphen in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So i'm trying to employ the use of hyphens in my URLs for readability but so far haven't found a way to make it work with mvc4.

I'll start with the code in the controller:

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.URL = Functions.fetchURL();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(LogonModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
         //omitted to save space

        return View(model);
    }


    public ActionResult Forgot_Login_Info()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Forgot_Login_Info(RetrievePasswordViewModel model)
    {
         //omitted to save space
        return View();

    }
```

So I'm using underscores for the name of the actions as seen with "Forgot_Login_Info" and that is the name of the view as well. For testing I also manually created a view called "Forgot-Login-Info"

In my global.asax.cs file i simply have this line for routes

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

which is the standard routing line with new projects for MVC4 and this is hooked to the "RouteConfig.cs" file and in that file here is the code I have, which I found in another question on this site.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public class HyphenatedRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
    {
        protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Replace("-","_");
            requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");
            return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
        }
    }



    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );



        routes.Add(
        new Route("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new RouteValueDictionary(
            new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
            new HyphenatedRouteHandler())
        );
    }
}
```

Lastly here is the  code for the "Index" view, which is where I have a link to the "Forgot_Login_Info".

```
 <div class="centerBlockItem" style="width:450px; text-align:center">
@Html.ActionLink("Forgot Password?", "Forgot-Login-Info")
    @Html.ActionLink("Forgot Password?", "Forgot_Login_Info")
</div>
```

Now I have the link 2 ways, 1 using underscore and the other using hyphen. According to what i've read in regards to the code I found for this purpose, Both links should open the "Forgot_Login_Info" view and not the "Forgot-Login-Info" view. But what I'm getting instead is the 2nd link works fine and the action name matches the view files name. But when I click on the first link, I get a 404 error because the system can't find the "Forgot-Login-Info" view file, even though I had manually created a file with that name for testing.

One more thing to note, the code in my routeconfig file, In the answer I had found it suggested I comment out the default route code lines and just leave:

```
routes.Add(
        new Route("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new RouteValueDictionary(
            new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),
            new HyphenatedRouteHandler())
        );
```

I had done this too and got the same results. Any ideas where I'm screwing things up?

Comment: This is an alternative: http://mvccoderouting.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Route+Formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out what I was doing wrong, I had this listed under the root routebundle.cs file but i was trying to make this work in an area, once I moved this code to the area registration file, it worked like a charm. If anyone needs my full code listing just ask and i'll post it all up.

Answer (score 0):

How is this helping SEO when the crawlers can still access the underscore version of the controller, thereby duplicating content. Struggling with this right now.